# How to print contents of Rich Text Box

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm making a text editor in C# and WPF.

How would I go about getting the contents of my RichTextBox `editor` and printing them with a printer? I already got this;

```
private void print(){
    PrintDialog printDialopg = new PrintDialog();
    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){

    }
}
```

Any guides, code examples or anything would be helpful!

Comment: A quick google search gave me [this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970917(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call a `PrintDocument` method.

```
private void print(){
    PrintDialog printDialopg = new PrintDialog();
    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
        pd.PrintDocument((((IDocumentPaginatorSource)yourTextBox.Document).DocumentPaginator), "printing as paginator");
    }
}
```